# How to fill a webform fast?

Tags: forms

My preteen boy has grown *really* fascinated by world flags and he thinks he can beat the [world record](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/426236-fastest-time-to-identify-all-national-flags) for that. Problem is, Guinness wants to use https://www.sporcle.com/games/g/worldflags and it's just impossible to type that fast. We tried Nuance Dragon Professional for voice but the recognition rate is nowhere near good enough -- not at all surprisingly, to be fair, I guess it's engineered more towards complete sentences than just single nouns.

What would you use? We have Windows 10 laptops, an iPad, multiple Android phones and tablets. (Even a Windows 7 laptop or two if older is helpful. If Linux is helpful, we can look into that too.)

Comment: I think typing is just part of the challenge, so if you can type fast and know how the country names are spelled you can still use this web site pretty fast: Type country name, press tab, press return - next flag.

Answer (score 1):

A text expanding software like [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) or [beeftext](https://beeftext.org) could help but would involve first creating shortcuts/acronymns and then memorizing those.

**Autohotkey**

This software can do pretty advanced things. You can also send Tab (next field) or Enter (to submit) as part of your script

```
; will expand the text usa to the text after typed anywhere/anytime its typed
::usa::United States of America
```

**beeftext**

Create a combo keyword `usa`, for example, then fill in the snippet `United States of America`. I believe tab character can also be used in the snippet `#{key:tab}`